# Characterization of Matrices with only one Element in every Row and Column

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Are the following kind of matrices categorized or studied in any way?
For example:

```
0 0 a 0 0
0 0 0 b 0
0 0 0 0 c
d 0 0 0 0 
0 e 0 0 0
```

If diagonal matrices only scale each eigenvector, these matrices transform one eigenvector to another and then scale them.

Comment: you have a diagonal matrix multiplied by a permutation matrix, $DP.$ the specific permutation matrix would have all your variable entries replaced by $1$ and is a power of a cyclic permutation; that matrix has all $1$ on the immedaite superdiagonal, then a single $1$ in position $(5,1)$

Comment: They are called *monomial matrices*.

Answer (score 1):

This is a generalized permutation matrix:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_permutation_matrix

I know them as the normalizer of the diagonal invertible matrices, but Wikipedia has a lot more it seems.